# Как сделать Бота для instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

в реальности возможно ли сделать бота для instagram, например отвечать на сообщения юзеров и т д? Если да, то какими способами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У них API приватное, поэтому тут два варианта: на гитхабе/pypi поискать готовые обёртки ([например эта](https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi)) или сниффить траффик с мобильного инстаграма/реверсить приложение и самому написать обёртку. Естественно такие решения использовать на свой страх и риск, аккаунт может отлететь в бан.